# C++ MinGW Linker Error _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE10_M_replaceEjjPKcj

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, libstdc++

I'm working on an assignment for university and I can run my program just fine via my IDE (CLion) and have it work. However, when I try to run the built executable manually on the same machine I get the following error:

[image: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE10_M_replaceEjjPKcj]

The long string: " _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE10_M_replaceEjjPKcj "

I'm building using MinGW32 with GCC/G++ versions 5.3.0 on Windows 10. The libraries I'm using which I compiled from source are GLEW 2.0 and GLFW 3.2.1. I'm also using stb_image.

My code is being built for the C++14 standard. I can not for the life of me figure out what is causing this error.

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(FlightSim)

#Set C++ standard to C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#Set project directory variables
set(SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(RESOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources")
set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes")
set(LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")

#Include library headers
include_directories("${INCLUDE_DIR}")

#Add source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")
add_executable(FlightSim ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Add static definition for GLEW
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)

#Link libraries
target_link_libraries(
        FlightSim
        "${LIBRARY_DIR}/libglew32.a"
        "${LIBRARY_DIR}/libglfw3.a"
#        "${LIBRARY_DIR}/libSOIL.a"
        opengl32.lib
)
```

Comment: Are you linking statically to these libraries? If that's the case, I'd be very careful. A popular cause of this problem is that some of the libraries are compiled with a version of Visual Studio that's different than the one you're using (since you're using MinGW). Can you verify that this is the case? You may try to resolve this issue by linking to shared libraries.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I am linking to the libraries statically as far as I am aware of. However, they have been compiled on my own machine from source using the MinGW compiler and not with Visual Studio. I am also not using Visual Studio at all in this project as I mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I finally fixed this issue after a few days.

The cause of this issue was that in my system PATH variable, there was a directory belonging to GTK Sharp which contained it's own version of the 'libstdc++-6.dll' file and this DLL file was being used instead of the one from my compiler.

After removing the conflicting DLL file from GTK Sharp I was able to compile my program and run it manually.

To check if there are multiple files with the same name in your PATH variable you can run the 'where ' command in the command prompt like so: 'where libstdc++-6.dll'.